# What is the function of the quotes in grunt.init.config

Tags: gruntjs

I see sometimes this in a gruntfile:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    'connect': {
        testserver: {
            options: {
```

Why does `connect` has quotes? I tried removing and it works anyway so I wonder why `'connect': {` and not just `connect: {`

Is there a "good practise" convention, or other convention about this? Or are these reserved words?

Comment: Quotes around object property names can be used to avoid certain keywords or special symbols (i.e. the JS interpreter would normally see a property name like `asdf+123` as an arithmetic expression and would error out during parsing it as an object property key name, but it will see `'asdf+123'` as a string usable as a property key name). Some people may put quotes around all property names just in case, but I'm not sure why it would have been put around that Grunt config object property in particular.